# Some of objects like dataConnectors, dataConnectorTypes of salesforce wave analytics API are not accessible

Tags: api, error, einstein-analytics

When i try to hit get API for wave object as services /data/v39.0/wave i am getting following response:

```
{

"dashboards": "/services/data/v39.0/wave/dashboards",
  "dataConnectorTypes": "/services/data/v39.0/wave/dataConnectorTypes",
  "dataConnectors": "/services/data/v39.0/wave/dataConnectors",
  "datasets": "/services/data/v39.0/wave/datasets",
  "folders": "/services/data/v39.0/wave/folders",
  "lenses": "/services/data/v39.0/wave/lenses",
  "query": "/services/data/v39.0/wave/query",
  "templates": "/services/data/v39.0/wave/templates"

}
```

But when i try to hit get API for following objects:

- dataConnectors
- dataConnectorTypes

i am getting error as:

> {
>       "message": "This feature is not currently enabled for this user.",
>       "errorCode": "FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED"
>   }

with status code as 403 forbidden. Whereas i am getting expected response for rest of objects like dashboard,dataset,folder etc.

Also there are some other objects like:

- Replicated Dataset
- Replicated Dataset Field
- Trendedreports

which are mentioned in API documentation for salesforce wave analytics but are not accessible. I am getting same error for these as well.

Can someone tell me what could be problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Replication Objects are not accessible because you will need to get Replication Feature enabled for the org .

To get more details on replication feature check [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_bi_integrate_replication.htm)

Similarly if you enable a third party data connector like informatica,mulesoft etc you will see dataConnectors enabled

Comment: How can i enable third party data connector?

Comment: You will need to contact the vendor .Lets say you need Mulesoft connector then you will contact Mulesoft

Comment: Are these end points using same APIs and What else do they do apart from being used for data upload for datasets objects?

Comment: Yes they do the same thing what datapart API does .It just saves bunch of time having to engineer again and most enterprises will already have one of those